# $K$-finite vector equivalent to being $\operatorname{Lie}(K)$-finite

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $(\pi,V)$ be a continuous representation of $G = \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ on a Hilbert space $V$ (not necessarily unitary).  Let $K$ be the orthogonal group in $G$, and  $\mathfrak k = \operatorname{Lie}(K)$.  A vector $v \in V$ is called *$K$-finite* if $\{\pi(k)v : k \in K\}$ is contained in a finite dimensional subspace of $V$.

A vector $v \in V$ is called *smooth* if for each $X \in \mathfrak g = \operatorname{Lie}(G)$,

$$d\pi(X)v := \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{\pi(\exp(tX))v - v}{t}$$

exists as an element of $V$, the limit taken in the norm topology

Let $v$ be a smooth vector.  I'm trying to understand why the following two conditions are equivalent:

(i): $v$ is $K$-finite.

(ii): $\{d\pi(X)v : X \in \mathfrak k\}$ is contained in a finite dimensional subspace of $V$.

Obviously, (i) implies (ii), but I'm having trouble seeing why the converse is true.  If all the vectors $d\pi(X)v : X \in \mathfrak k$ are contained in a finite dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$, this means that $d\pi$ restricts to a Lie algebra representation $\mathfrak k \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(W)$.  If we *knew* that $\pi|_K$ stabilized $W$ (precisely what I want to prove), then the well known relation

$$\pi(\exp(X))v = \exp(d\pi(X))v \tag{$\ast$}$$

holds for all $X \in \mathfrak k$.  Since the image of $\exp: \mathfrak k \rightarrow K$ is a finite index subgroup of $K$, equation ($\ast$) would prove that $W$ and hence $v$ is contained in a finite dimensional $K$-stable subspace.

Comment: Is the point that a finite-dimensional subspace of a topological vector space is closed, and/so a convergent sequence (of partial sums of infinite sum) ... convergent in the larger space... in fact has a limit inside the subspace?

Comment: I don't see how that would imply what I want.  If we let, say, $W$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $V$ containing $v$ and all the vectors $d\pi(X)v : X \in \mathfrak k$, and $W^{\perp}$ be a complement to $W$, then from $V = W\oplus W^{\perp}$ we can write
$$\pi(\exp(tX))v = v_t + v_t'$$
so that 
$$\frac{\pi(\exp(tX))v -v}{t} = \frac{v_t - v}{t} + \frac{v_t'}{t}.$$

This implies that $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{v_t  -v}{t} = d\pi(X)v$ and $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{v_t'}{t}$, but this doesn't immediately appear useful.